# Symfony2 Forms: automatic register block in forms

Tags: symfony

I have some form and if user isn't logged in yet i want to show some additional fields (like email, username) in this form and validate it.

Now i do it in that way:
Create new `FormType`:

```
class QuickRegisterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('username')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array(
                'QuickRegister'
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quick_register';
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
$user = $this->getUser();

$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($message, array(
    'cascade_validation' => true
));

$formBuilder->add('body', 'textarea');

if (!$user) {
    $formBuilder->add('quick_register', new QuickRegisterType(), array(
        'property_path' => 'sender'
    ));
}
```

In template:

```
{% if form.quick_register is defined %}
    {# render this fields #}
{% endif %}
```

And just after $form->bind($request); i get valid user in $message->getSender(); Everything is good! But i need to perform some other actions just after form validation:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $sender = $message->getSender();
    if (!$sender->getId()) {
        // perform some work with just registered user
        // like sending email, generate passwords, so on
    }
}
```

And this actions will be generally the same for such form from all project, so i want to optimize it.

At first i think i can create new service in DI container and just call it like

```
$this->container->get('my.user_service')->afterQuickRegister($sender);
```

But now i read about Form events in symfony2 on page http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

I don't understand right now, can i use it for my purposes? Can i create such form subscriber in DI container? And generally, can i somehow change `User` just after creation? What is right form event for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement it with FormEvents.

```
form.type.quick_register:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type\QuickRegisterType
    arguments: [ @form.type.quick_register.subscriber ]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: quick_register }
```

And pass subscriber by `form.type.quick_register.subscriber` service. In subscriber i check form validation in POST_BIND event and do my stuff. Great!